# Should MongoDB Inserts/Updates/Upserts/Deletes be published?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

As of right now, I have my MongoDB "Selects" in \server\publications.js, such as:

```
Meteor.publish("jobLocations", function () {
  return JobLocations.find();
});
```

...and am subscribing to those in \client\main.js, such as:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe("jobLocations");
 . . .
```

...but I have my Inserts/Updates/Upserts/Deletes in \both\methods.js, like so:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'insertJobLocation': function(username, jobLoc, placename, st8OrProvince, postalcode, xcoord, ycoord) {
        JobLocations.insert({
            jl_jobloc: jobLoc,
    . . .
```

...and am calling them from \client\templates\whatever.js, like so:

```
'submit form': function(event, template) {
    . . .      
    Meteor.call('insertJobLocation', jobloc, placename, st8OrProvince, 
        postalcode, xcoord, ycoord, function(err) {
        . . .
```

This works, but is it wrong[-headed]?

Should *all* the MongoDB code be published/subscribed to (IOW, located in \server\publications.js and \client\main.js?

Comment: subscribe only to what you really need. `Meteor.methods` are finally executed on the server you just need to send an `_id` to really know what to modify.

Comment: What do you mean? I really need everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read, the rule of thumb is to subscribe to what you need to display on the client browser.
This will return all items/fields in the `JobLocations` collection, so if this collection is large you may want to limit what you publish with `query` or `field` params:

Before:

```
Meteor.publish("jobLocations", function () {
  return JobLocations.find();
});
```

Once you get a lot of data (or want to hide sensitive data !):

```
Meteor.publish("jobLocations", function (jobLocParam) {
  var selector = {
    jobLoc: {$in: jobLocParam},
  }
  var options = {
    sort: {placename: 1},
    fields: {jobLoc: 1, placename: 1},
    limit: 20
  }
  return JobLocations.find(selector, options);
});
```

All of those fields are optional, but I figured I'd give you a few examples.  `selector` can just be `{}` if you want to return everything, and you can limit which fields are published with the `fields` param (also optional).  Publications can also take parameters, so if you would like, you can pass a `jobLoc`, or an array of them, through the publication when the template is created.

Hope this helps !

Comment: So by saying, "subscribe to what you need to display on the client" does this mean "Selects" (Finds) as opposed to Updates, Deletes (removes), Upserts, and Inserts? BTW, that was a great example you gave; just what the PhD ordered...Posthole Digger, that is.

Comment: Subscriptions are only relevant for reading data (finds).  All of the other CRUD operations (create, update, delete) are handled on the server, but can be exposed via methods.  If you want to update a specific `jobLoc` from the client, you will need to subscribe to the `_id` so you can tell the server which document to update.

Comment: You should be conscious of security when exposing CRUD methods to the client, you do not want anyone to be able to update / delete / insert docs from the client.  Without something like [this](https://github.com/ongoworks/meteor-security/), I could open up the chrome js console and make changes to your data